# How to map several API Gateways to the same custom domain with versioning in the URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

We have several AWS SAM projects that we want to host under a single custom domain.

We're currently able to do this by defining a BasePathMapping inside each project.  For example, `orders` maps to `api.example.com/orders`, and `users` maps to `api.example.com/users`.

This works fine for us, but we'd also like to version our API, so the URL looks like `api.example.com/v1/users`.  Unfortunately, a BasePathMapping cannot contain nested paths, like `v1/users`, and setting the base path mapping to `v1` wouldn't work because it would not be unique across our services.

One workaround I've found is to version within the service, which would look like `api.example.com/users/v1`, but we'd like to avoid that if possible.

Is there another way that we can do this using separate SAM services?

Comment: One option is to use a separate domain for the services. Then you have `users.api.example.com/v1` and `orders.api.example.com/v2`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  That would work, but we'd like to try to avoid more than 1 level of subdomains if possible.

Comment: Hi any solution?

Comment: No, we ultimately decided against this pattern, and instead went with a single Api Gateway to direct traffic into our application.